# Where can I find wave scatter tables (joint probability Hs vs T) for certain coastal regions?

Tags: ocean, waves, open-data, wave-modeling

I am struggling to find a database or free source of joint probability of significant wave height and period, i.e. wave scatter tables. Data for buoys are useful, however not available for regions like Africa.

For example, *oceanor* provides software based on *hindcast* (http://www.oceanor.no/Services/Worldwaves/) which is not available for free. The *hindcast* of NOAA could be used to process data from their ftp server, however it's a tedious task processing terabytes of historical data!

Is another source available to public?

Comment: I am not aware of other publicly available hindcast sources, but NOAA Wavewatch hindcast should be very feasible to process - you only need 2 2-dimensional arrays for your region. That is the route that I would take if I had to accomplish this task.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @milancurcic! I suppose that you are talking about: http://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/CFSR_hindcast.shtml or http://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/download.shtml? But still I need to donwload huge global grids and then extract the data needed, or I got it wrong? Btw I am intersted for a shallow nearshore region in africa, thus    I suppose SWAN is needed.